# how do I make a rectangle in python?

Tags: python, graphics

How do I make a rectangle with Height and Width parameters, using the graphics package in python?

```
Rectangle(RecWidth,RecField);
```

Comment: don't know about graphics package, but general way is to provie coordinate of one of the rectangle conrner along with widht and height.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: I am using a graphics package, from a 3.2 version of python.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin() 
rect = Rectangle(Point(20, 10), Point(10, 20))
rect.draw(win)
```